# correct way of writing html to php links

Tags: php, html

I need help cause i dont know how to translate is html to php well

`echo "<li class='list'><a class='menuItem'  name='link1' href='Registrate.php?var="$_SESSION["DepartmentSession"] ="Admisiones""> Admisiones </a></li>";`

Comment: i keep getting errors

Comment: did you start your `session_start();` before this echo?

Comment: What you are doing here.. You want to parse the value/assign the value ??

Comment: yes i want to on click to save value in the session of multiple

Comment: how you want your output to be? It's unclear.

Comment: You have invalid quotes in your code. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Check This one

```
echo "<li class='list'><a class='menuItem'  name='link1' href='Registrate.php?var=".$_SESSION['DepartmentSession']."=Admisiones'> Admisiones </a></li>";
```

Comment: thanks that fixed my problem that was really simple problem that i got stuck on

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your quotes is correct. From what I see. Your code contain invalid quote overlap.

```
echo "<li class='list'><a class='menuItem'  name='link1' href='Registrate.php?var=".$_SESSION["DepartmentSession"] ."='Admisiones' "> Admisiones </a></li>";
```

or the safest way is to just write it in html

```
<li class='list'>
  <a class='menuItem' name='link1' href='Registrate.php?var=<?php echo $_SESSION["DepartmentSession"] ?>=Admisiones' > Admisiones </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check this...**

```
echo "<li class='list'><a class='menuItem'  name='link1' href='Registrate.php?var=".$_SESSION['DepartmentSession']."=Admisiones'> Admisiones </a></li>";
```